# <!DOCTYPE html> - Document Type Declaration must appear only once

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      class="light"
      ng-app="app"
      ng-controller="appController"
      id="ngApp"
      xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"
      xmlns:ui="ui-router">
```

In Visual Studio 2013 this always gives a problem in the editor and the DOCTYPE is underlined in green with a message saying:

```
Document Type Declaration must appear only once
```

Has anyone else found a solution to this problem. Note that with a simple `<html>` this does not happen. Code works in the browser but for all versions of VS2013 Update 1-4 I see this green squiggly line under DOCTYPE.

Comment: can you give some more insight on your question ?

Comment: Is it a Visual Studio question? Are you having any working issues or warning on any browser?

Comment: It's most likely some extension spazzing out,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check and see if there is a layout file.  If you using the template for MVC that Visual Studio provides then your layout file will be located at `Views/Shared/_Layout`.  There you can see that `<!DOCTYPE html>` has already been inserted.

Comment: I'm getting this warning when looking at my _Layout.cshtml file

Comment: @GeekyMonkey I would do a solution wide search using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F` and make sure the `Look in:` dropdown says `Entire Solution` and seach for `<!DOCTYPE html>` making sure it only appears in your views in the `_Layout.cshtml` file.  Anywhere else it should be deleted.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: I only have it in _Layout files, still I'm getting that warning. Actually, even if I have it in only one _Layout file in the entire solution, that warning still doesn't disappear.

Comment: Same thing here with Visual Studio 2015 and MVC 5. It displays the same error, apparently without reason.

Comment: I had this showing up in visual studio 2015 while I was debugging. When I ended the debugger it disappeared. Presumably because it had two copies of the home page open at once

Comment: Can i use it again in a index page where "Layout = null;" It worked before, now this issue came. i'm using vs 2019. asp core 3.1